# Получение значения чекбокса в переменной

Tags: javascript, html

Как получить значение чекбокса для дальнейшего использования в JS?

Пример HTML:

```html
<HEAD>
<script>
  var chb1Value = 0;

function showValue(chb) {
  if (chb.checked) {
    document.getElementById("info").innerText = chb.value;
    return +chb.value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("info").innerText = "";
    return 0;
  }
}
</script>
</HEAD>

<p>
      <span id = "tool"><input type="checkbox" id="chb1" name="inf"  value=2 onclick="chb1Value = showValue(this);console.log(chb1Value);" />
      <label for="chb1"><span></span>инф</label></span>
      <!-- <span id="inf"></span> -->
    </p>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="info"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function getCheckboxInfo() {
  var chb1 = document.getElementById("q");
  console.log(chb1.id, chb1.value, chb1.name, chb1.checked);
  var chb2 = document.getElementById("a");
  console.log(chb2.id, chb2.value, chb2.name, chb2.checked);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="q" name="qwer" value="12"  />
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="asdf" value="43"  />

<br>

<button onclick="getCheckboxInfo()">Click</button>
```

> выводить значение чекбокса на страницу и чтобы оно менялось при
>   включении/выключении чекбокса

```js
var chb1Value = 0;

function showValue(chb) {
  if (chb.checked) {
    document.getElementById("info").innerText = chb.value;
    return +chb.value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("info").innerText = "";
    return 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="chb1">Test<label>
<input id="chb1" type="checkbox" value="123" 
  onclick="chb1Value = showValue(this);console.log(chb1Value);" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="info"></span>
```

Comment: Получается чтобы вывести эту переменную нужно сделать так 
HTML
 `<div id='txt1'></div> <div><button onclick="getCheckboxInfo()">Click</button></div>` JS `function getCheckboxInfo() { var chb1 = document.getElementById("inf"); console.log(chb1.id, chb1.value, chb1.name, chb1.checked); var chb2 = document.getElementById("ekonom"); console.log(chb2.id, chb2.value, chb2.name, chb2.checked); } window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = chb1; }`

Comment: @Sem объясните словами, что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: Хочу выводить значение чекбокса на страницу и чтобы оно менялось при включении/выключении чекбокса

Comment: А как можно вывести значение не в сам чекбокс, а в строку снизу(или где угодно, но только не в нем самом), просто у чекбоксов, в моем случае, уже есть подписи

Comment: @Sem см. изменение в ответе

Comment: остается одна проблема, у меня присутствует` <label for=...>` и следовательно `onclick` не подходит. И еще, он может это значение помещать в переменную, так как мне его надо будет еще изменят(складывать, умножать).

Comment: @Sem см. изменение в ответе. Не понял, в чем проблема с `label`-ом.

Comment: @Sem хм, было бы странно, если бы он работал в отсутствие `onclick="..."`

Comment: Все работает, я просто забыл посетить офтальмолога